# Regular Expression For indenfity google search pages

Tags: php, regex

I would like to get the regular expression to identify whether a url is a google search home page or search results page .

Comment: and what have you tried for that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
(https?:\/\/www\.google\.(?:(?:com)|(?:co\.in)).*#q=.+)
```

For Google search result url.

Since in Google the searched word will be there , after `q=`

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sS5pZ3)**

**Explanation:**

[image: Explanation]